# Why does MYSQL Sleep(x) go on forever?

Tags: mysql, sql, sleep

I have a basic SQL query

```
DO SLEEP(2)
```

However, when I run it, it just goes on forever until it reaches a timeout message.

I have already tried

```
SELECT SLEEP(2)
```

and it still goes on forever.

There are no error messages, the request just goes on forever.

Comment: Please post full code. Are you using some kind of `WHILE` loop?

Comment: And please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it to use it like this

```
SELECT ...
DO SLEEP(5);
SELECT ...
```

or

```
UPDATE Table1 SET...
SELECT SLEEP(5);
SELECT ...
```

Then it will wait 5 Secondes between the sql commands